# wp_localize_script and host/browser cache

Tags: plugin-development, wp-localize-script

I am writing a custom made plugin that will have advanced JS scripts, in order to preload relevant data i am localizing scripts.

PHP

```
$post_array = my_function_to_get_my_data();
wp_localize_script('registered_script', 'serverData', array( 'posts' => $post_array ) );
```

JS part:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($){
    $.each( serverData.posts, function( id, content ){
      console.log( content );
    }
});
```

Will the data passed via wp_localize_script be up to date on the client side ( meaning that caching will not be an issue ). ?

Answer (score 4):

The data passed by `wp_localize_script()` is output in a `<script>` tag in the page HTML. So if you have this:

```
wp_localize_script( 'registered_script', 'serverData', array( 'posts' => $post_array ) );
```

This will be on the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* <![CDATA[ */
    var serverData = { "posts": [] };
    /* ]]> */
</script>
```

This means that if your page HTML is cached with something like WP Super Cache or WP Rocket this data will also be cached. So if you need the data to be 100% up to date, to the second, then you should retrieve fresh data via AJAX in your script.

Keep in mind that `wp_localize_script()` was originally designed to provide localized/translated strings to scripts, and those don't need to be updated anywhere near that frequently.

Comment: OK, I understand how it works now. so wp_localize_script is not adding anything to 'registered_script', it is simply adding a new inline script to the page. This could indeed be an issue if the HTML is cached, but i was more afraid of JS files caching. Thanks !